# How much repository interfaces must created in Repository Pattern?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

Assume we have following classes:

```
public class User
{
    //User Definitions Goes Here
}

public class Product
{
    //Product Definitions Goes Here
}

public class Order
{
    //Order Definitions Goes Here
}
```

Having above models, Should I Create only one repository like:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    //IRepository Definition Goes Here
}
```

Or it is better to have multiple repository:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    //IUserRepository Definition Goes Here
}

public interface IProductRepository
{
    //IProductRepository Definition Goes Here
}

public interface IOrderRepository
{
    //IOrderRepository Definition Goes Here
}
```

And what is each pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **must** . You create as many as the app needs.You could have a repository interface for each business object and a generic interface.

Something like

```
interface ICRUDRepo<T> //where T is always a Domain object
{
    T get(GUid id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Save(T entity);
 }

//then it's best (for maintainability) to define a specific interface for each case

interface IProductsRepository:ICRUDRepo<Product>
{
    //additional methods if needed by the domain use cases only

    //this search the storage for Products matching a certain criteria,
    // then returns a materialized collection of products 
    //which satisfy the given criteria
    IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(SelectByDate criteria);
 }
```

It's all about having a clean and clear abstraction which will allow proper decoupling of the Domain from persistence.

The generic abstraction is there so that we save a few keystrokes and *maybe* to have some common extension methods. However using a common generic interface for these purposes doesn't really count as DRY

Comment: I avoid putting query methods like `GetProducts` on my Repositories. It tends to reduce their OCP compliance. I opt for individual Query Objects.

Comment: Query object are ok for reporting purposes. For Domain purposes it makes sense to be part of a repo.

Comment: Why? What difference does it make?

Comment: Once you have a `Get(id)` it makes sense to find in the same place queries needed by the domain like `GetByName(name)`,`GetAll()`,`GetBy(Criteria)` . The repo should serve the Domain as best as it can.

Answer (score 1):

If you adopt the first approach, you avoid repeating yourself, satisfying DRY principles. But you break separation of concerns principles by lumping unconnected items in one interface and any implementing class.

If you adopt the second approach, you implement good separation of concerns, but risk repeating yourself, so breaking DRY principles.

One solution is a third way: do a mixture.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Query {get;}
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<IUser>;
public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<IProduct>;
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<IOrder>;
```

This approach then satisfies both principles.

Comment: -1 Bad advice. _IQueryable_ is a sign of a leaking abstraction **and** an improper use of the repository pattern. You tell the repository **what** you want, not **how** to do it. IQueryable is about building a query i.e the 'how' and it requires you to know about all the involved entities that would have the required data.

Comment: @MikeSW, Whether to use `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` is a debate without end. Plenty of framework interfaces are LSP disasters just waiting to happen, or already have. But if you an live with that, `IQueryable` may be preferable to `IEnumerable` for large data sets. It's a pragmatic compromise.

Comment: It's not. IEnumerable and IQueryable are implementation details. The issue is their purpose. IQueryable's purpose is to build a query. IEnumerable is just to enumerate something. The whole point of the repository pattern is abstract storage access. If the repo let's its user to build queries then you assume your storage is an sql or supports sql semantics and you have to know the 'tables' involved. It defeats the purpose of the pattern. For large data sets there is pagination.

Comment: @MikeSW, OK, I'll consider myself better educated now than I was before and will accept what you say. I've updated my answer to use `IEnumerable` :)

Comment: It's still wrong :) your repository is still exposing a way of building a query. That "feature" shouldn't exist at all regardless of how you choose to implement it.

Comment: @MikeSW, is that just semantics though, or have I misunderstood something else.In other words `IUserRepository.Query()` might just be better called ``IUserRepository.GetAll()`?

Comment: In other words, the repository builds the query (if any) as an implementation detail and returns the final result. Any further processing from the client will apply strictly to the returned data, it won't even touch the db.